# Need to import a large database (8.8M zipped, 67M unzipped), is it better to use PHP + cron job or something else?

Tags: php, cron, download, unzip

General question.  One of my sites is on a LAmP server and I need to download a large .zip file from an external site.  The file is zipped (.zip) and is 8.8M large.  It contains a .txt tab-delimited dataset that is 67M large.  I will need to download the file, unzip it, and import it into MySQL on a daily basis.

Is it better do do this using PHP and a cron job or something else?  Why?

Comment: I'd suggest this question might be better suited to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/); but voting for Webmasters, since it doesn't seem to be *quite* right for 'sysadmins and desktop support professionals'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysqlimport` to import tab-delimited files into MySQL via a cron job and skip PHP altogether.  Assuming `mysqlimport` meets your needs, this is probably best because PHP isn't adding any value.  PHP is usually configured with memory limits that a process like this is likely to exceed, so you'll bypass that potential hassle too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need.  Can mysqlimport import an external file directly or would I first have to download the file locally and then run mysqlimport?

Comment: If by "external file", you mean a URL, then no, it can't do that.  You need to download the file to a filesystem that can be accessed by the shell invoking `mysqlimport`.